# Не подключается React-router

Tags: react-router

Выбивает ошибка ./src/components/index.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\TicTacRedux\src\components'

Подключил react-router:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import Toolbar from './Toolbar'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Toolbar />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

В packaje.json также все подключено:

```
{
  "name": "jus",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Несколько раз перезапустил, все равно вылетает ошибка. Что не так?

Comment: Иногда нужно просто перевести текст ошибки на русский.....

Answer (score 1):

Выполните `npm i react-router-dom` или `yarn add react-router-dom` для устранения проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите npm install react-router-dom, перезагрузите сервер или npm run start. Проверяйте

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нет модуля "react-router-dom", в packaje.json подключен "react-router", это другой модуль